# augmented images does not store in their own classes directory

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I am new in DCNN. Moreover, I am working on image data augmentation and I have been writing code of augmentation. Moreover, I have 5 classes in the dataset i.e. Grass, Flower, Fruits, Dust, and Leaves  Thus, the train set in is also consist of 8 classes. However, after augmentation, all of the augmented data has been store in the train folder but it does not store in their individual class. Besides that, I have been applied the directory manually for example:

```
directory = ('/content/dataset/train/Grass'),
save_to_dir = ('/content/dataset/train/Grass')
```

Unfortunately, it does not work, and augmented images, not generated.

Therefore, I want to store augmented data with their raw that is has been already stored in the train folder. In short augmented data of Grass, classes will be stored in the grass classes folder that exists in the train folder that is as similar given bellow:

```
directory = ('/content/dataset/train/Grass'),
    save_to_dir = ('/content/dataset/train/Grass')
```

Using platform: Google Colab

My code:

```
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rotation_range=45,
    width_shift_range=0.2,
    height_shift_range=0.2,
    shear_range = 0.2,
    zoom_range = 0.2, 
    horizontal_flip=True,
    fill_mode = 'nearest')

i = 0

for batch in datagen.flow_from_directory(directory = ('/content/dataset/train'),
                                         batch_size = 32,
                                         target_size = (256, 256),
                                         color_mode = ('rgb'),
                                         save_to_dir = ('/content/dataset/train'),
                                         save_prefix = ('aug'),
                                         save_format = ('png')):
  i += 1
  if i > 5:
    break
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what you want is

```
import tensorflow as tf
import cv2
import os
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
sdir= r'c:\temp\people\dtest' # set this to the directory holding the images
ext='jpg' # specify the extension foor the aufmented images
prefix='aug' #set the prefix for the augmented images
batch_size=32 # set the batch size
passes=5  # set the number of time to cycle the generator
datagen = ImageDataGenerator( rotation_range=45, width_shift_range=0.2, height_shift_range=0.2, shear_range = 0.2,
                                zoom_range = 0.2,  horizontal_flip=True, fill_mode = 'nearest')
data=datagen.flow_from_directory(directory = sdir, batch_size = batch_size,  target_size = (256, 256),
                                 color_mode = 'rgb', shuffle=True)
for i in range (passes):
    images, labels=next(data)
    class_dict=data.class_indices
    new_dict={}
    # make a new dictionary with keys and values reversed
    for key, value in class_dict.items(): # dictionary is now {numeric class label: string of class_name}
        new_dict[value]=key    
    for j in range (len(labels)):                
        class_name = new_dict[np.argmax(labels[j])]         
        dir_path=os.path.join(sdir,class_name )         
        new_file=prefix + '-' +str(i*batch_size +j) + '.'  + ext       
        img_path=os.path.join(dir_path, new_file)        
        img=cv2.cvtColor(images[j], cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        cv2.imwrite(img_path, img)
print ('*** process complete')
```

This will create the augmented images and store them in the associated class sub directories that have the original images in them.

Comment: Yes, I applied this but there is also the same problem. All images stored in the same places. I want to store them in their own folder @gerry p

Comment: you want each augmented image in a separate folder?

Comment: see amended answer

Comment: Sir, Thanks for Your support. But there are other things that I want. Actually, I have 8 classes in the train folder. Each folder contains several image data. Therefore, I want to generate augmented data and store that aug data into the same folder with raw data.  Moreover, I have updated my question with a more clear explanation by a new post. The link is here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66887186/augmented-images-does-not-store-in-their-own-classes-directory-with-raw-data-tha @Gerry P

Comment: see modified answer

Comment: Sir, it is possible to generate a particular number of images for individual classes. for example, I have a class that consists of the height number of images i.e. 762, and other classes have 405, 304, 502, etc. Therefore I want to generate the images to make balances in order to 762? @GerryP