# Balancing on the several imbalanced classes of image dataset

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, data-augmentation

I have a dataset that has 12 classes in the base directory. However, these 12 classes consist of several amounts of Images. The number of images of 12 classes is inconsistent therefore its impacts the total accuracy. Thus, should I apply the data augmentation to the particular classes that have a low amount of data?

Image data of each class:

```
#Dummy Classes

    [AAAA: 713
    ABCD: 274
    ACBD: 335
    ADBC: 576
    BBBB: 538
    BACD: 607
    BCAD: 253
    BDAD: 257
    CCCC: 463
    CABD: 309
    CBAD: 452
    CDAB: 762]
```

Therefore, if should I apply data augmentation to increase the amount of data in the lower classes, as well as I apply the data augmentation but it does not increase the image data. Besides that, I want to generate the augmented data with the raw data that means the input and out directory will be the same.

Code of Augmentation for particular (Individual Classes):

```
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator


datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rotation_range=45,
    width_shift_range=0.2,
    height_shift_range=0.2,
    shear_range = 0.2,
    zoom_range = 0.2, 
    horizontal_flip=True,
    fill_mode = 'reflect', cval = 125)

i = 0

for batch in datagen.flow_from_directory(directory = ('/content/dataset/ABCD'),
                                         batch_size = 317,
                                         target_size = (256, 256),
                                         color_mode = ('rgb'),
                                         save_to_dir = ('/content/dataset/ABCD'),
                                         save_prefix = ('aug'),
                                         save_format = ('png')):
  i += 1
  if i > 100:
    break
```

Output: `Found 0 images belonging to 0 classes.`

Comment: I have a solution with `flow_from_dataframe`. Is that okay with you? Since `keras` augments images on-the-fly, you do not have to create all the augmented images before feeding them to your model. `ImageDataGenerator` will apply random augmentation to your images, so even though you feed an image, e.g. `img1.png`, the image will be different every time because of the random augmentations, e.g., `img1_aug0.png, img1_aug1.png ...`.

Comment: Sir, thanks for Your kind cooperation. Could You please share the solution precisely? I am waiting for Your further response @Prefect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned, I am using `flow_from_dataframe`, so you might start with creating a csv file for your dataset, in case you do not have one. My idea is to repeat the current dataset to a fixed number of samples for each label, e.g., you want 762 sample for every label in your dataset. Here is my approach with some dummy dataset.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
import cv2

cv2.imwrite('temp.png',np.random.rand(3,3)) # Create a dummy image to be able to use flow_from_dataframe later

labels = [] # Create some unbalanced dataset
for i in range(10):
    labels.append('a')

for i in range(5):
    labels.append('b')

for i in range(3):
    labels.append('c') 

# Create a dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'img_path':['./temp.png']*len(labels),'label':labels})

# print(df.head())

def balance_data(df,target_size=12):
    """
    Increase the number of samples to number_of_samples for every label

        Example:
        Current size of the label a: 10
        Target size: 23

        repeat, mod = divmod(target_size,current_size) 
        2, 3 = divmod(23,10)

        Target size: current size * repeat + mod 

    Repeat this example for every label in the dataset.
    """

    df_groups = df.groupby(['label'])
    df_balanced = pd.DataFrame({key:[] for key in df.keys()})

    for i in df_groups.groups.keys():
        df_group = df_groups.get_group(i)
        df_label = df_group.sample(frac=1)
        current_size = len(df_label)

        if current_size >= target_size:
            # If current size is big enough, do nothing
            pass
        else:

            # Repeat the current dataset if it is smaller than target_size 
            repeat, mod = divmod(target_size,current_size)
            

            df_label_new = pd.concat([df_label]*repeat,ignore_index=True,axis=0)
            df_label_remainder = df_group.sample(n=mod)

            df_label_new = pd.concat([df_label_new,df_label_remainder],ignore_index=True,axis=0)

            # print(df_label_new)

        df_balanced = pd.concat([df_balanced,df_label_new],ignore_index=True,axis=0)


    return df_balanced

df_balanced = balance_data(df)
# print(df_balanced)

# A particular image will be transformed to its various versions within the augmentation step 
image_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rotation_range=45,
    width_shift_range=0.2,
    height_shift_range=0.2,
    shear_range = 0.2,
    zoom_range = 0.2, 
    horizontal_flip=True,
    fill_mode = 'reflect', cval = 125)

image_generator = image_datagen.flow_from_dataframe(
            dataframe=df_balanced,
            x_col="img_path",
            y_col="label",
            class_mode="categorical",
            batch_size=4,
            shuffle=True
            )

# x,y=next(image_generator)
```

I hope the code is self explanatory. Let me know if you need further assistance.

Comment: Sir, I found this output `Found 36 validated image filenames belonging to 3 classes. However, there is nothing updating and there nothing updated on the number of images. You are right, I want to make the classes balance by generating a height number of images. Therefore, I also mentioned the class name. After applying this augmentation I will split them as train, valid, and test set. Therefore, I want to make the classes balance@Prefect

Comment: What exactly do you mean by nothing updated? Yeah, so in my example, you are getting 12 images for each class, although they were unbalanced (10, 5 and 3) in the original dataset.

Comment: Sir, this is my output `Found 36 validated image filenames belonging to 3 classes`. However, images do not increase in the main dataset. Because after running augmentation and before augmentation the number of images is the same i.e. 5539. But it is created as temp.png. Therefore, how may generate images into the imbalance classes. @Prefect

Comment: You should adjust my approach to your data. Because I don't have your data, I just created some dummy image nd labels. You should create a dataframe with two columns including your image paths and your labels. I would suggest you reading the [documentation](https://keras.io/api/preprocessing/image/).

Comment: Thank You, Sir. This is my main directory 'datagen.flow_from_directory(directory = ('/content/dataset/ABCD')' for class 01. Could You assist me then it would be very helpful for me @Prefect

Comment: Sir, I have updated my question with a new post. The link is here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66930116/balancing-on-the-particular-imbalanced-classes-of-image-dataset @Prefect